# change the optimizer of the model and restore the original model from the checkpoint, but there is an error happened

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I train the model, called as model A. Then, I change the optimizer and initialize the model by the checkpoint from model A. But there is an error happened.
Because I want to save all the variables of the new model, I didn't use the import_meta_graph('**.ckpt') and don't set the variables in the tf.train.Saver(). 
How can I solve this problem?

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=args.num_snapshot) 
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(path).model_checkpoint_path)
```

There is the error log:

```
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a Variable name or other graph key that is missing from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:
Key OptimizeLoss/fully_connected_11/biases/Adam not found in checkpoint
[[node save/RestoreV2 (defined at ***.py:130) ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the next line of code:

```
restore_vars = (list(set(tf.get_collection_ref(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES))
    .intersection(tf.train.list_variables(checkpoint_dir))))

saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_can_be_restored)
```

Related topic is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731175/how-to-only-restore-variables-in-the-checkpoint-in-tensorflow).

You might also try to restore with your original optimizer and [change the optimizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47626254/changing-optimizer-in-keras-during-training) after restoring from the checkpoint.

Comment: But if you do like this, the variables which I created in the new model cannot be saved. I want to save all the variables in the new model.

Comment: @CongMa you use this saver once to restore the weights and than create a different saver that saves everything